# How to add Expected Condition into generic findElement method

Tags: c#, selenium

Please see this function:

```
public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
    return wait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
}
```

As you can see in this function i am using `ElementIsVisible` `ExpectedConditions` but i want to be able to send to this function `ExpectedConditions` in case i want another one.
Any suggestions ?

**Update**

```
    public static IWebElement find(By by, Func<ExpectedConditions, bool> condition, int timeOut)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
        webDriverWait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
        IWebElement elem = webDriverWait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
        return elem;
    }
```

So now its almost done, i sill cannot replace `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` with the `condition`:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenQA.Selenium.By' to
>   'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions'

Comment: I think you have mixed up C#and Java code. I think you shld use DefaultWait instead of webdriverwait.  The second parameter should be the C# equivalent of the return of the call ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by). Then you dont need the by parameter in the method. I had written my code in Java.

Comment: What another expected conditions do you want to add??

Comment: PresenceOfElement, ElementToBeClickable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `Selenium` `WebDriver` `C#` bindings `ExpectedConditions` implementation only has a few methods and their is no way to add multiple `ExpectedConditions` together.

But you can create a custom wait like you're asking for would look something like as below :

```
public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));

     return webDriverWait.Until(d => d.FindElement(by).Enabled
      && d.FindElement(by).Displayed);
 }
```

**Edited** :- If you want different `ExpectedConditions` according to you choice, try as below :

```
public static IWebElement WaitAndFindElement(Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> expectedCondtions, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));

     return webDriverWait.Until(expectedCondtions);
 }


//Now you can call above function as
IWebElement el = WaitAndFindElement(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by), timeoutInSeconds);
```

Or

```
IWebElement el = WaitAndFindElement(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by),  timeoutInSeconds);
```

Comment: But this is not ExpectedConditions, i want to wait every time for different ExpectedConditions (elementVisible, presemceOfElement, elementToBeClickable...), any chance to move Grasshoppers java code to c# ?

Comment: @DanaYeger do you want something like edited answer... see and let me know...:)

Comment: Yes but this have compile  error: The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code, and if changed var into ExpectedConditions --> The type arguments for method 'DefaultWait<IWebDriver>.Until<TResult>(Func<IWebDriver, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I try to use it this way: IWebElement el = WaitAndFindElement2(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector(""), 30)); and got this error: No overload for method 'ElementToBeClickable' takes 2 arguments

Comment: @DanaYeger No, you are calling wrong, try as : `IWebElement el = WaitAndFindElement2(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("")), 30);`...just arguments mistake... correct it

Answer (score 0):

In java i wld try something like this. No idea about C# though

```
private <T> void webwait(int timeOut, int retry, ExpectedCondition<T> expCond)   {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut, retry).until(expCond);
}
```

to use it

```
webwait(2, 100, ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
            By.id("divid")));
```

I have a void return, in your case you can return the element. Then you can remove the genric T and put in ExpectedCondition parameter.